# Is axios Async?

Tags: javascript, axios

Is Axios async by it self, or is it needed to wrap it around an async function?
For instance is this async :

```
function axios () {
  axios.get()
}
```

Or should I write it like this:

```
async function axios () {
  await axios.get()
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `axios.get` returns a promise, whether you wrap it into a function, an async function, or not at all. How you *deal* with that returned promise is what you have to decide, whether to `await` it or anything else.

Comment: your overwriting axios with a function called axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Axios` returns `promise` so you can use `async` `await` or `.then`

async await :

```js
async function call() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('api/test')
}
```

then :

```
 function call() {
  axios.get('api/test').then(({data}) => {..operation here..})
}
```